# Javascript createElement with indented html

Tags: javascript, html, icheck

I am creating a for dynamically with javascript, so I have a bunch of js lines that are creating my html code.

E.g.

```
var container_fluid = document.createElement("div");
container_fluid.className = "container-fluid";

var row = document.createElement("div");
row.className = "row";

//pull-left div
var pull_left = document.createElement("div");
pull_left.className = "pull-left";

var label_input = document.createElement("label");
var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
checkBox.className = "minimal";
checkBox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
checkBox.name = value.name;
```

The problem is that the generated html tags are not formatted (single line code) and because of this I have some spacing issues between text and radio inputs.

Here is an example:

[image]

The first set of radio are coded from the html file and the radio after the break line are the one generated with javascript.

So maybe you will think is a CSS problem but no, when I manually edited the html code from chrome inspector and added "Enter" between tags all was solved.

So what can solve this problem?

Comment: Insert `document.createTextNode(' ')` between the elements or use CSS to define the spacing (probably better).

Comment: Well, the root cause may not be CSS, but CSS can solve it :). Otherwise, @Felix has the right of it; just add a text node.

Comment: Thank you. I used createTextNote, if I use CSS the margin-left will be from the element or from the space/indentation?